# How do I use a cloud-init ubuntu image with Rancher on vSphere, with a network without dhcp?

Tags: vmware, rancher, vsphere, cloud-init

Long story short: using a network without dhcp to deploy a new cluster from Rancher to vSphere causes a timeout on "waiting for ssh".

I am using a network protocol profile and vApp settings to set the static ip on the nodes.

I followed this guide:

https://www.virtualthoughts.co.uk/2020/03/29/rancher-vsphere-network-protocol-profiles-and-static-ip-addresses-for-k8s-nodes/

But when I disable cloud-inits initial network configuration, the nodes are never assigned the static IP from vApp. Without disabling the initial configuration, the first boot takes around 2 minutes (because it waits for dhcp, and fails), but it DOES apply the static ip from vApp afterwards - but unfortunately the 2 minutes it waits for dhcp is enough for Rancher to timeout waiting for ssh.

Answer (score 0):

It would appear that my issue was that the network assigned to the nodes were unable to provide ipv6 through dhcp, and this caused the netplan to not apply the ipv4 static ips - but also didn't throw an error.

I found it through:

journalctl -b -u systemd-networkd

After I updated the netplan configuration with:

link-local: [ipv4]

The nodes now get their static ip's correctly